# How can I remove a registered geofence?

Tags: android, google-api-client, geofencing

I have some code that should be removing a registered geofence but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

This is the code that I have for removing:

```
Constants.LANDMARKS.remove(item);
populateGeofenceList();
LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, requestID).setResultCallback(this);
addGeofencesButtonHandler();
```

LANDMARKS is a HashMap that is storing a string for a key and latitude and longitude. "item" is a String that should be a key found in the HashMap. RequestID is an ArrayList containing the item.

The addGeofencesButtonHandler method is just to make sure the remaining Geofences are registered, I probably don't need to call this method.

Here is the code for the populateGeofenceList method:

```
public void populateGeofenceList() {
    for (Map.Entry<String, LatLng> entry : Constants.LANDMARKS.entrySet()) {
        mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(entry.getKey())
                .setCircularRegion(
                        entry.getValue().latitude,
                        entry.getValue().longitude,
                        Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS)
                .setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                .build());
    }
}
```

I also have an SQLite database for storing some other data. Should I be keeping latitude and longitude in that database instead of a HashMap?

Comment: Are you getting any errors when trying to remove your Geofences? Please paste the error log as well.

Comment: I have gotten crashes but I'm not able to reproduce them when connected to my machine. Also I believe I'm using the HashMap remove() method incorrectly which is part of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what the problem is, needed to mGeofenceList.clear() before populateGeofenceList()

Also I don't know if it helped but I made an iterator to iterate through the HashMap to make sure they key existed before removing it.